# How does python know what __name__ should be?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, python-import, python-internals

Running a script from the command line, the `__name__` attribute of that script will be `'__main__'`. But `import`ing that script from a different location, the `__name__` attribute of that module will be the name of the script.

How does python know what the value of `__name__` should be? Can a script tell that it's being imported, and set the `__name__` attribute accordingly?

Comment: In case it is a module `__name__` is the name of the module.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited for accuracy

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#__name__)

> The import machinery fills in these attributes on each module object during loading, based on the module’s spec, before the loader executes the module.
>
> **`__name__`**
> The `__name__` attribute must be set to the fully-qualified name of the module. This name is used to uniquely identify the module in the import system.

So these magic attributes are assigned during the so-called "import machinery". You can read more details [about that system in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** How does python know what the value of `__name__` should be?

Well, if you write `import foo` Python will look for a module named 'foo' and set its name to 'foo'.

> **Q:** Can a module tell that it's being imported, ...

Yes, it can. Usually people do that with [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) -- if the test passes, it generally means that the module is being executed, if it fails it generally means that it is being imported.

A particular case where this test will fail is when you have a module named `__main__` (in a file named `__main__.py`).

If you want to be 100% more sure, you can inspect the [frames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) and see if the module is on top of the stack:

```
f = sys._getframe()
if f.f_back is None:
    # We're at the top of the stack: this module is being executed.
else:
    # There's a frame on top of us: this module has been imported.
```

> **Q:** ... and set the `__name__` attribute accordingly?

And yes, you can change `__name__` to whatever you want by simply setting it:

```
__name__ = 'bar'
```

Although there's no reason to do so, other than generating confusion and possibly introducing bugs.